# Neo4j 3.5 fails creating index

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

A little while after

```
neo4j> CREATE INDEX ON :Temporal_Event(name);
```

I received:

```
2018-12-28 08:37:05.791+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2018-12-28 11:11:46.963+0000 ERROR Client triggered an unexpected error [Neo.DatabaseError.General.IndexCorruptionDetected]: Index `Index( GENERAL, :Temporal_Event(name) )` has failed. Drop and recreate it to get it back online. Actual failure:
==================
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index key-value size it to large. Please see index documentation for limitations. | GB+Tree[file:/SSD/data/databases/neo4j-dbpedia-AI.db/schema/index/native-btree-1.0/8/index-8, layout:GenericLayout[version:0.5, identifier:5643935348791705600, fixedSize:false], generation:2/4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.WorkSyncedNativeIndexPopulator.add(WorkSyncedNativeIndexPopulator.java:94)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.BatchingMultipleIndexPopulator.lambda$flush$2(BatchingMultipleIndexPopulator.java:170)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.NamedThreadFactory$2.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index key-value size it to large. Please see index documentation for limitations. | GB+Tree[file:/SSD/data/databases/neo4j-dbpedia-AI.db/schema/index/native-btree-1.0/8/index-8, layout:GenericLayout[version:0.5, identifier:5643935348791705600, fixedSize:false], generation:2/4]
    at org.neo4j.index.internal.gbptree.TreeNodeDynamicSize.validateKeyValueSize(TreeNodeDynamicSize.java:369)
    at org.neo4j.index.internal.gbptree.InternalTreeLogic.insert(InternalTreeLogic.java:353)
    at org.neo4j.index.internal.gbptree.GBPTree$SingleWriter.merge(GBPTree.java:1281)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeIndexUpdater.processAdd(NativeIndexUpdater.java:133)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeIndexUpdater.processUpdate(NativeIndexUpdater.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeIndexPopulator.processUpdates(NativeIndexPopulator.java:286)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeIndexPopulator.add(NativeIndexPopulator.java:164)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.WorkSyncedNativeIndexPopulator$IndexUpdateApply.process(WorkSyncedNativeIndexPopulator.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.WorkSyncedNativeIndexPopulator$IndexUpdateWork.apply(WorkSyncedNativeIndexPopulator.java:168)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.WorkSyncedNativeIndexPopulator$IndexUpdateWork.apply(WorkSyncedNativeIndexPopulator.java:148)
    at org.neo4j.util.concurrent.WorkSync.doSynchronizedWork(WorkSync.java:231)
    at org.neo4j.util.concurrent.WorkSync.tryDoWork(WorkSync.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.util.concurrent.WorkSync.apply(WorkSync.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.WorkSyncedNativeIndexPopulator.add(WorkSyncedNativeIndexPopulator.java:81)
    ... 5 more

==================, reference 40308cf1-008c-4580-a7d4-19610e3a712d.
```

I dropped the index as per the message.

How do I delete the offending node such that the index will work?
How do I obtain the offending node id?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size limitations for different data types [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/index-configuration/schema-indexes/#index-configuration-limitations).

Once you are sure about the maximum allowed size for your data type(Say MAX_SIZE=4036, please confirm on the above link).
You can find all the offending nodes using this query:

> ```
>  MATCH (n:Temporal_Event) WHERE size(n.name) > MAX_SIZE RETURN n.id LIMIT 10
> ```

You can delete these nodes or just delete the property whichever you prefer.

If you want to delete these nodes, use the following query

> ```
> MATCH (n:Temporal_Event) WHERE size(n.name) > MAX_SIZE DETACH DELETE n
> ```

This query first deletes all the relationships of these nodes (DETACH) and then delete the nodes(DELETE).

There are some workarounds to this, I haven't tried but you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082839/neo4j-fails-indexing-property-size-is-too-long/52083750).

Comment: Unexpectedly I get :neo4j> MATCH (n:Temporal_Event) WHERE size(n.name) > 4036 RETURN n.id LIMIT 10;
+------+
| n.id |
+------+
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+

Comment: I think these nodes don't have 'id' property set.

Comment: Try returning the node instead of id.:   
MATCH (n:Temporal_Event) WHERE size(n.name) > MAX_SIZE RETURN n LIMIT 10

Comment: Tried this - and deleted all the offending nodes. Unforntaely the error still persists.  Found the following bug report: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12038